# C++11 regex_search not working as intended

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm on CentOS 7, using `gcc version 4.8.5 20150623`, compiling with the `-std=c++11` flag. My code is as such: (note that I am `using namespace std;`)

```
bool compare_regex(const std::string & detection, std::string regstr)
{
        bool found = false;
        regex reg_matcher(regstr, std::regex_constants::extended);
        smatch m;
        if (regex_search(detection,m,reg_matcher)){
            found = true;               
        }
        else{
            log_print("REGEX NOT MATCHED.");
        }
        return found;
}
```

This code does not return `true`, even when I call it with `detection = "The year 1864 was a year I tested my code on string"` and `regstr=18`. I've tried more complicated regexes as well, but none of them work. What might be going wrong?

Comment: This function produces UB; control flow can leave the function without a value being returned. *"Flowing off the end of a function [...] results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function."*

Comment: forgot to copy the end of my code, fixing.